# azure will not recognize my user with oauth

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to add a single-sign-on to my web-app with azure active directory. When directed to the ms Sign-In screen I get the message "There was an issue looking up your account. Tap Next to try again."

I created the app in "App registrations" and retrieved the client and tenant id from there. When executing the below code I'm getting prompted for my username (Sign-In).
The app is also linked to the user account.

Code behind my app "login" button

```
 $.ajax({
            processData: true,
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/configuration/test_sso',
            success: function (response) {
                var w = window.open('about:blank');
                w.document.open();
                w.document.write(response);
                w.document.close();
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
```

my controller code

```rb
   def test_sso
    client_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    tenant = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    uri = URI.parse("https://login.microsoftonline.com/#{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.read_timeout = 480
    http.open_timeout = 240
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
    request.add_field('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    request.body = "client_id=#{client_id}&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/myapp/oresponse/&scope=openid&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=67890"
    response = http.request(request)
    render :text => response.body
  end
```

I'm directed to the Microsoft "Sign-In" dialog but when entering my azure ad account name and hitting next I get the message:
"There was an issue looking up your account. Tap Next to try again."

I would expect that I can enter my username and password on the ms screen, when successful I would expect the redirect_uri to be called

Comment: The issue you're experiencing right now has something to do with your browser. Can you try with different browser and see if it helps.